# Append word to input file name for output file name

Tags: python, file, networkx

I am trying to read in some data, process the data, and write the results to a CSV saved with the original filename + the word "folded".  I'm using

`sys.argv` to pass the input filename, and thought that I could just create a new variable such as `filename = sys.argv[1]+'_folded.csv` but I ended up with `file.csv_folded.csv`.

How can I do this so my output file is saved as file_folded.csv?

**Simplified code example:**

```
import sys
import networkx as nx

G = nx.read_edgelist(sys.argv[1], delimitier=',')

fileout = sys.argv[1]+'_folded.csv'
nx.write_edgelist(G, fileout, delimiter=',')

Did you rename the file with the third option?
```

Comment: consider using library `fileinput`, this could greatly simplify your processing, if you have multiple files and even, if you want the files rewritten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are already specifying `filename.csv` in your command line argument so you want to replace that with your special extension to do that you could:

```
 file_name = sys.argv[1].replace('.csv', '_folded.csv')
```

Answer (score 2):

Split the file extension and only use the prefix:

```
orginal_name = sys.argv[1]
prefix = orginal_name.rsplit('.')[0]
fileout = prefix + '_folded.csv'
```

or just pass the `out` file name from terminal (which I prefer), for example:

```
python program.py file.csv file_folded.csv
```

Then in code just use `sys.argv[2]` for `out` file name.

Answer (score 1):

You could `slice` the .csv off of sys.argv[1]:

```
fileout = sys.argv[1][:-3] +'_folded.csv'
```

Answer (score 1):

To not assume the `.csv` extension, use [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext):

```
name, ext = os.path.splitext(sys.argv[1])
file_name = name + '_folded' + ext
```