# How can I name output file by including the input file name in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to name an output file by adding the string "resampled" to the input file name

```
outputfile = '%s.tif' % '{0}+ {1}'.format(inputfile, '_resampled')
```

How can I do this so my output file is saved as `inputfile_resampled.tif`?

For example:

`NIR` would become `NIR_resampled.tif`.

Comment: Why the complicated-double string formatting? Why not just `"{}.tif".format(inputfile+ '_resampled')`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add an id to filename before extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487758/how-to-add-an-id-to-filename-before-extension) ; or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24409984/append-word-to-input-file-name-for-output-file-name

Comment: ``` "{}.tif".format(inputfile+ '_resampled')```  didn't work!

Comment: Check out the links above. That should give you your answer. The above suggestion will not work if `inputfile` is a full path and not just the file's name...

Answer (score 1):

Using f-string

```
outputfile = f"{inputfile}_resampled.tif"
```

Using standard string

```
outputfile = "{}_resampled.tif".format(inputfile)
```